# What the actual file name of .tfignore file?

Tags: tfs

I always read that I need to create a `.tfignore` file for TFS to exclude my selection of files.

But what's the actual name of the file? If I'm trying to rename an empty file to `.tfignore`, File Explorer tells me that the file is required to have a file name, not just an extension.

So what's a valid example for a valid `.tfignore` file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was just struggling with the same issue. I found that if you create the file with the name `.tfignore.` (note the . at the end it recognizes that before the last "." is the filename. When it is created/renamed, the last "." will go away.

Comment: Nice trick. The file might disappear if you rename it but just refresh the folder to see it again.

Answer (score 18):

1. Open a command prompt.
2. CD to the directory you want to create the .tfignore file in (i.e. the solution root)
3. Type "echo > .tfignore". This will create a blank file you can then edit.